# Multiple uses for [indirect] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The tag [indirect](/questions/tagged/indirect) has no tag wiki nor excerpt, and is used for multiple types of questions about:

- Excel's `INDIRECT()` function
- Used as a meta-tag as the English definition of the word
- Indirect function calls
- Indirect classes

Should the questions be edited, or should the whole tag be burninated?  There are only a few questions, so I think an edit spree could be doable.

Comment: IMO we should add tags like [tag:excel-indirect] and apply where needed and burninate the rest.

Comment: excel+indirect exist in 12 questions only. It would not take much time. Also, it'll clear 1/3rd of the total questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone created [excel-indirect](/questions/tagged/excel-indirect), which took care of the majority of cases.  It's worth noting that other spreadsheet programs, including Google Docs/Drive, include an `INDIRECT` function.  There was one question tagged, which I added to the [excel-indirect](/questions/tagged/excel-indirect) list even though it's not *quite* correct... it's close enough in context.

That left about five questions about various indirect addressing modes and operands in assembly languages, and various other uses, none alike.  The various assembly questions were so different that it couldn't justify the creation of any additional indirect tags.

The tag has been purged, and is now on my list of *73* tags I keep dead every day.

Comment: *73 a day*? That must be a fun way to start the morning...

Comment: Thankfully you can do a multi-tag search for up to 50 at a time, so it's only two bookmarks.  :)